# How many indexes do I need with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have some questions about indexes usage in MongoDB.

Lets say I have a collection of product documents, such as this:

```
{
    "name": "Sony phone",
    "description": "Android phone made by Sony...",
    "category": ["technology", "phones"],
    "stock": 70,
    "price": 100,
    "options": {
        "colors": ["red", "black", "blue"],
        "material": ["plastic", "wood", "aluminium"]
    }
}
```

Now, lets say that sometimes I'll query the products collection:

- only by `name` (text search)
- by `name` and `description` (text search)
- by `category` (show me all products in the `technology` category)
- by `options->material` (show me all products made of `wood`)
- by `category` and `options->material` (show me all products in the `technology` category that are made of `wood`)

How many indexes should I create? One for each field? One for each field + one for each combination of queries?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can use an index when the queried field(s) are *contained* in an index. Furthermore, there can be only on text index per collection (though multiple fields can be indexed).

So, as per your example, you would need two indices:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({
  name:"text",
  description:"text"
})
```

With that, you would search for "Sony" like

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: "Sony"} })
```

Which would return every document in which Sony occurs in either "name" or "description".

Next, you would need an index over "category" and "options.material":

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({
  category:1,
  "options.material":1
})
```

When doing a query on the shell, you can check wether the index is used by appending `.explain()` to your query.

Note: I don't see the point of having an options subdocument. The same information is contained within

```
{
  _id: "Sony Experia Z3",
  description:"foo bar baz",
  material:["plastic","metal"],
  colors:["black","blue"]
}
```

Which is simpler, does not have redundant field descriptions and makes use of an already existing unique index for the phone name.

Comment: Just to make it clear. `ensureIndex({a:1, b:1})` will let me search by `a`, `b`, or `a` and `b` at the same time, right? About the 1 text index per collection, do you know if there are  any "workarounds" or tricks/tips I could use to improve the situation?

Comment: @alexandernst I showed you the workaround. Simply index multiple fields in the text index. And for the compound index: yes, that's right. Investigate with `.explain()`. ;)

Comment: No, I mean, can I make it somehow so  I could search only in "name" and only in "description", but not both at the same time?

Comment: @alexandernst In that case, create an addional index over name and description and use `db.collection.find({name:/Sony/i})` or `db.collection.find({description:/Sony/i})`, respectively.

Comment: But that is going to do a regex search, and what I'm asking for is a text search. Can't I have a real text search for each field separately?

Comment: @alexandernst: Nope, since you can only have one text index and this either spans multiple fields or one. Though I fail to see in which way a regex scan should be a problem, considering the use cases I imagine for a collection like this.

Comment: This was just an example. I do have some legit cases where I'd like to perform an actual text search on a particular field :(